# Is it okay to Touch ID/Face ID as an account login method for an app?

Tags: biometrics, touch-id, face-id

I'm currently developing an iOS app that requires login of some kind. Is it ethical/okay to authenticate a user through biometric means, since the biometric information will have to be stored on the server?

Comment: What do you mean is it ethical? It is an authentication method, and you should not have any biometric information stored in your server.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is it ethical/okay to authenticate a user through biometric means, since the biometric information will have to be stored on the server?"

Irrelevant. TouchID + FaceID is [implemented using the "secure enclave" of the iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587): biometric data is never exposed to the user's application. So you cannot capture biometrics yourself. The best you can do is take a photo of the user's face, which requires the user's permission to use Camera anyway. It's the same on Android: applications simply ask the OS "please authenticate the user" and the OS responds with a simple yes/no answer: there is no API in iOS or Android to read raw fingerprint, face model, or iris data.

Outside of iOS, supposing you're writing a traditional application that uses hardware to capture this information without using any OS-provided user authentication feature, then that's a legal and business question and not a software-engineering question and it should be answered higher-up in your organisation. However if you have been instructed to build software that does capture this kind of information and you know it isn't necessary and is being done without the user's informed consent then it becomes an engineering ethics question and then you speak to your own lawyer and consider rejecting your boss' request and/or becoming a whistleblower. (IANAL but I believe this would be *very illegal* in the EU under various Data Protection laws dating back to at least 1998, because you cannot legally capture and store personal data that you have no legitimate purpose to retain, especially without the user's consent - and you do not need raw fingerprint or other biometric data to authenticate a user)

Comment: He won't get into legal issues as Apple will not allow the app into the marketplace. If it's a corporate app then it falls on the business that's intending to use it to instruct people that it does that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Touch ID/Face ID as an account login method, however there are a few caveats to what you're asking.

- 1: Secure Enclave (Biometrics are stored locally w/o access to your
  server."
- 2: You'll need to have a manual login as a backup and a    primary
  prerequisite.
- 3: Yes it's ethical, with user permission, but you CANNOT use it by    default or Apple will
  reject your app immediately. It has to be an    option enabled by the
  user.